# How to properly override a method returning an instance of generic class in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an abstract generic class:

```
abstract class BasePresenter<View, Router> {

    var view: View? = null
    var router: Router? = null

    abstract fun OnStart()
    abstract fun OnStop()

}
```

And I have a subclass of it:

```
class NewsListPresenter : BasePresenter<NewsListView, MainRouter>() {
    override fun OnStop() {
        //
    }

    override fun OnStart() {
        //
    }
}
```

Also I have a class with a protected abstract method:

```
protected abstract fun getPresenter() : BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>
```

And I have it overridden in a subclass:

```
override fun getPresenter(): BasePresenter<Any?, Any?> {
    return NewsListPresenter() as BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>
}
```

Android Studio highlights the overridden function cast saying "This cast never succeed". I tried using `in Any`, `out Any` and `*` and it doesn't work. When I tried to use `*` I could not use the `getPresenter()` method in the class where it is originally defined. Android Studio complains about type mismatch: required Nothing?, found BaseFragment.
In Java the same code would work perfectly and I didn't think that it would be a problem in Kotlin. What is the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The "cast can never succeed" warning is incorrect here. The correct message for the warning should be "unchecked cast" because this cast may or may not be correct, but this cannot be discovered by running your program.

There's [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6611) in the tracker which in fact was [fixed](https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin/commit/4b6b35dadf68a9088c58c14ed3d49f9d307ff4d0) several days ago. The fix will likely make it to Kotlin 1.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BasePresenter<*,*>` for that.

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections):

> Star-projections
>
> Sometimes you want to say that you know nothing about the type
>   argument, but still want to use it in a safe way. The safe way here is
>   to define such a projection of the generic type, that every concrete
>   instantiation of that generic type would be a subtype of that
>   projection.
>
> Kotlin provides so called star-projection syntax for this:
>
> For `Foo<out T>`, where `T` is a covariant type parameter with the
>   upper bound `TUpper`, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>`. It
>   means that when the `T` is unknown you can safely read values of
>   `TUpper` from `Foo<*>`. For `Foo<in T>`, where `T` is a contravariant
>   type parameter, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<in Nothing>`. It means
>   there is nothing you can write to `Foo<*>` in a safe way when `T` is
>   unknown. For `Foo<T>`, where `T` is an invariant type parameter with
>   the upper bound `TUpper`, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>`
>   for reading values and to `Foo<in Nothing>` for writing values. If a
>   generic type has several type parameters each of them can be projected
>   independently. For example, if the type is declared as interface
>   `Function<in T, out U>` we can imagine the following star-projections:
>
> `Function<*, String>` means `Function<in Nothing, String>`;
>   `Function<Int, *>` means `Function<Int, out Any?>`; `Function<*, *>`
>   means `Function<in Nothing, out Any?>`. Note: star-projections are
>   very much like Java’s raw types, but safe.

Comment: I described that in my question. With star projections I can not assign a value to `getPresenter().view` или `getPresenter().router`. Android Studio complains about type mismatch.

Comment: I suspect what you are describing is a compiler bug. I recommend reporting the issue with an example. As a workaround you can cast the `BasePresenter<*, *>` returned by `getPresenter()`: `(getPresenter() as BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>).view = something`.